# RDP vs VNC - what exactly is the difference in regards to screen sharing?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, vnc, nx

I've been trying for way too many hours now to get a similar remote desktop experience as Windows -> Windows, but on Windows -> macOS. As far as I know from my testing, I need to use VNC if I want to mirror the exact configuration of the host (1 monitor = 1 monitor gets mirrored), and RDP if I want something else (like "fake virtual screens").

My Windows setup consists of 3 monitors. My Windows laptop has 1 monitor (built-in). When I use the RDP client in Windows on my main PC and I connect to my Windows laptop, it acts exactly like if I connect the 3 monitors to the laptop directly. If I right click on my desktop and pick `Display settings`, it actually shows 3 monitors connected, even though the laptop only has 1.

If I instead use VNC Viewer, Remotix, NoMachine, and programs like that, and I connect my main PC with 3 monitors to my MacBook Pro, I can only see 1 monitor/screen. The resolution is 2880x1800, which matches the MacBook's resolution.

What is the difference between all of these different protocols? I've read about VNC, RDP, NX, and probably a few others, but I haven't been able to find the exact search term, that allows me to find a macOS program, that allows it to create "fake virtual displays", like Windows essentially does.

My guess would be RDP, as that's what Windows uses, but I haven't found a single software on macOS that claims it can create "fake virtual displays".

NoMachine has a feature where it can span the host display(s) across the guest's displays, but by enabling that, it just spanned a single 2880x1800 screen across my 3 monitors, which essentially means I would have to plug in 3 identical monitors to my MacBook, if I wanted the same experience on my Windows PC.

Comment: VNC takes what is on the screen and reproduces it. This is accurate but bandwidth heavy. RDP tries to be more intelligent - hooking into the OS to pick up the instructions. For example if the IS creates a popup with some text in it VNC will transmit it as pixels.  RDP will transmit it as "draw a box and add this text" - which much less data - a major concern for real time video.

Comment: VNC always transmits image data. RDP however can transmit Windows GUI events and Windows data. Image data is only transmitted if no other possibility is available. Effectively this means that RDP works with way slower connections than VNC and show a better quality than VNC.

Comment: @davidgo and Robert thanks - makes a lot of sense. Same conclusion I've come to, when I checked how much bandwidth Windows -> Windows RDP uses. Basically none, if nothing is happening on the screen. Is RDP a Windows-only protocol?

Comment: RDP is definately NOT a Windows only protocol. I use it under Linux. I don't do macs, so can't recommend anything but have a look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-mac

Comment: @davidgo That's the client and not server, unfortunately

Comment: Try https://www.nuords.com/ for a server.

Comment: @davidgo Only gives me one choice and that's the 2880x1800 resolution of the MacBook's screen. Gave me an error when I tried on my 4K monitor, where it said it couldn't set the requested resolution: https://i.imgur.com/2sAmIih.png